# Unable to change MSBuild path in MSBuild Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have added my `MSBuild v.16` to my path parameter on my windows machine.

If I run the `NuGet restore` for my project from my `cmd`, it works correctly.

If I run this command from my local `jenkins`, it picks the `MSBuild v.14` under auto detect.

I tried giving the path to `MSBuild` in `jenkins Global Configuration` `MSBuild` but it does not resolve the problem.

Comment: Jenkins normally runs executors under different user - check from you pipeline what is the logged in username, then configure the tool for this user.

Comment: I have only one user on my jenkins and thats me. Also, the MSBuild plugin is configured as global configuration. So my understanding is this case should not arise.

Comment: I re verified the setting in hudson.plugins.msbuild.MsBuildBuilder.xml and it looks fine.